# How can I organise my own proctor in South America for a foreign university exam?

Tags: exams, online-learning, policy

I am taking an online accredited course at Illinois and I need to have someone in South America proctor a test (preferably Bolivia, Argentina, or Chile).

Anyone have any suggestions for how to accomplish this? I've looked on many websites  (including universities and libraries) and struggling to find a resource. Maybe it's more informal? This test will need to be a physical test.

My course specifically puts these requirements for a proctor. There may be wiggle room with some communication.

- Principal or Superintendent of Educational Service Region, School, or District
- Dean, Academic Department Head, Extension or Correspondence Administrator, Registrar, or Official Testing Service of an Accredited University or College
- Education Officer (Armed Services Personnel Only)
- Full-Time High School or College Instructor
- Librarian at your local community library

Specific details on proctor [information is here](https://netmath.illinois.edu/proctors).

Comment: I don't understand why you need someone proctoring a test when you're the one _taking_ the course. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The point of the proctor is to validate there is no cheating. While I will be taking the test they need to assure the university that the test was taken fairly.

Comment: Yes, but it's a university's duty to organize the proctoring.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Please see [Illinois Online program web page](http://online.illinois.edu/getting-started/other-important-info-for-online-students/exams-and-proctors): _It is your responsibility to arrange for an approved proctor to supervise any off-campus examinations_

Comment: @scaaahu Thanks! But what a dubious practice! Apart from the fact that one pays and has also to organize their exams, such a practice certainly leaves a lot of room for organizing cheating at a local level with proctor's consesus.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to quote or summarise the course’s criteria for a proctor? Otherwise your question is not really answerable.

Comment: Look into ProctorU.com.

Comment: Embassy is usual.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I've added the proctor requirements.@LeonMeier, I'll call the embassy on Monday to see if they would be able to do it.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: I agree the practice of scheduling your own proctoring is not ideal. I ran into issues with it when I moved and now again when I'm traveling.

Comment: In case of an embassy: I've never used this service myself, but I did see that certain countries offered this service in their embassies or even consulates.

Comment: The last two bullets look like the most practical options.  Just start asking people if they'll proctor for you.  Show them the instructions.  I don't think this needs to be a big deal.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and close the question -- now that you've listed the options, I don't think this is an academic question anymore, you just need to ask (or hire) a librarian or teacher to proctor you.